# Add more values to same key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I want to make know if there is a command that can do this:

```
>>>A=dict()
>>>A[1]=3
>>>A
   {1:3}
>>>A[1].add(5)        #This is the command that I don't know if exists.
>>>A
   {1:(3,5)}
```

I mean, add another value to the same key without quiting the old value added.
It is possible to do this?

Comment: store values in a list and just append.

Comment: you probably just want to use defaultdict and default it to a list and append

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the dictionary values into [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq):

```
>>> A = dict()
>>> A[1] = [3]
>>> A
{1: [3]}
>>> A[1].append(5)  # Add a new item to the list
>>> A
{1: [3, 5]}
>>>
```

You may also be interested in [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), which has functionality similar to [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) but without the need to import:

```
>>> A = dict()
>>> A.setdefault(1, []).append(3)
>>> A
{1: [3]}
>>> A.setdefault(1, []).append(5)
>>> A
{1: [3, 5]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of type `list` will create an empty list in case you access a key that does not exist in the dictionary so far. This often leads to quite elegant code.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d[1].append(3)
>>> d[1].append(2)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [3, 2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a defaultdict eliminates the "special case" of the initial insert.

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = defaultdict(list)

for num in (3,5):
    A[1].append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others pointed out, store the values in a list, but remember to check if the key is in the dictionary to determine whether you need to append or create a new list for that key...

```
A = dict()
if key in A: A[key].append(value)
else: A[key] = [value]
```